# Search multiple criteria in a Google sheet and return latest date

Tags: google-sheets, search, return

I am making a new sheet. B2:D2 - Cuvee, Sweet Pea, Zurkle (strains),
A - Dispensary (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ele1sfanpaXYdC4Ng2eWZSPDCCliguEf_ndep_REYU/edit#gid=0)

I want to search another sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SvVyTrHO9saAZrr9DGxrSUNjZr-Y1JfPdSuwng50QE8/edit#gid=0) for the following criteria:
A: Product (B:D above)
D: Dispensary, and
E: Date
and return the last/latest date in the new chart. i.e. return the last date a specific product was purchased by a specific dispensary into the new sheet.

I am new at this and can get the formula for searching the criteria, but do not know how to return the latest date.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @JohnBroux just create a link it will say anyone with the link can access your sheet. Click share on the top right. But I recommend not sharing two google sheets but instead combining them into one with a sheet with the desired output even if it is hard coded.

Comment: sheets are private

Comment: Should work now. Sorry.

Comment: do you need the result in a separate spreadsheet? or just another sheet is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Example]

Assume that your need to place data in a separate spreadsheets, here is the answer:

Place this formula in 'B3' of your 'Chart 2' spreadsheet.

Since this formula uses `IMPORTRANGE()` function to get your source data, you may need to Accept it to load data from other spreadsheet on the 1st run.

```
=LAMBDA(SOURCE,DISPENLOOKUP,PRODUCTLOOKUP,
 LAMBDA(PRODUCT,DISPEN,DATE,
  MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(DISPENLOOKUP),COUNTA(PRODUCTLOOKUP),LAMBDA(ROWINDEX,COLINDEX,
   IFERROR(TEXT(MAX(
    FILTER(DATE,SEARCH(INDEX(DISPENLOOKUP,ROWINDEX),DISPEN),SEARCH(INDEX(PRODUCTLOOKUP,COLINDEX),PRODUCT))
   ),"dd/mm/yyyy"),"")
  ))
 )(INDEX(SOURCE,,1),INDEX(SOURCE,,2),INDEX(SOURCE,,5))
)(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SvVyTrHO9saAZrr9DGxrSUNjZr-Y1JfPdSuwng50QE8/edit#gid=0","Sheet1!A1:E"),"WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"),$A$3:$A,$B$2:$2)
```